# How to get the count of inserted rows in "insert ignore stament"

Tags: mysql

I am doing bulk insert and inserting 0.5 million  tokens in the database with insert `"ignore statement"`. in 0.5 million  tokens there can be duplicate tokens.
so if i insert 0.5 million tokens in the database with insert ignore statement then there is no guarantee that all of tokens are inserted into the database because of duplicate tokens.

After doing insertion i want to know how many tokens are inserted into the database. some people are suggesting to use `affected_rows` columns to get count of inserted (affected) rows. But affected_rows doesn't give the output of current sql statement it gives the output of last sql statement.

Please tell me the best way to get count of inserted rows with insert ignore statment.

Comment: Are you using 0.5 million INSERT statements, OR 1 INSERT statements with 0.5 million values ?

Comment: 1 insert with 0.5 million rows...

Answer (score 1):

Put `select row_count();` just after the `insert` statement to get the number of rows inserted.

eg:

```
insert ignore into tbl(col1) values (1),(2); select row_count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a single SQL insert ignore would work with affected_rows. Not sure tho how would that turn out performance wise since it's 0.5 mil rows to enter.

Anyhow, here's a solution I tried and works with 4 values in a signle INSERT.

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','test');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO test1 (Name, Attribute, Val) VALUES ('ai', 'blue', '1j'),('ai1', 'white', '2j'),('ai2', 'black', '3j'),('ai1', 'green', '4j')";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
printf ($mysqli->affected_rows);
?>
```

Comment: what if another insert from another process(request) executes before "printf ($mysqli->affected_rows)" statement then it will give count of this insert and not the one that you have mentioned in your example.